# "A sight for sore eyes": with sounds?

Tags: word-usage, idioms

You have this somewhat informal idiom: "*a sight for sore eyes*":

> : a person or thing that you are very glad to see 
>    - *After being away from home for so long, my friends and family were a sight for sore eyes*.
>
> ([*Merriam-Webster Learner's*](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/sight))

There are [examples](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+sight+for+sore+eyes) which don't involve human beings. [Possibly](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22sight%20for%20sore%20eyes%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1993,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=9f4mVb7fCNO2yATQlYCACw) used more often with people, but sometimes used to describe something beautiful and heart-warming, as in a scenery or with nature.

Is there an equivalent or similar idiom for *sounds*? As in related to the feeling of hearing voice of those people you were away from, the sound of a long forgotten engine, or sounds in nature?

Comment: "Music to my ears".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [phrase](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/music+to+ears) you're looking for is

**Music to my ears.**

> a welcome sound to someone; news that someone is pleased to hear.
>
> A: *Here's your paycheck for this month. B: Ah, that's music to my ears!*

You could also say something like:

> Being back at home and hearing the children laughing was *music to my ears*.
>
> The purring of my Mustang's engine was *music to my ears*.
>
> I went camping for the first time in years and hearing the sounds of the forest was *music to my ears*.

You can also turn it into a simile by adding *like*.

> It was **like** *music to my ears*.